# VBA - System does not support the specified encoding

Tags: excel, web-scraping, vba

### Run-time error '--1072896658 (c00ce56e)': System does not support the specified encoding

I'm trying to pull pricing data from this website:  [http://web.tmxmoney.com/pricehistory.php?qm_symbol=^TTUT](http://web.tmxmoney.com/pricehistory.php?qm_symbol=%5ETTUT). I keep getting the error "Run-time error '--1072896658 (c00ce56e)': System does not support the specified encoding".

I've used the code provided below to pull HTML data from most websites. This one is the only one which gives me this error. I think it is possible that i'm getting the error because the website uses Javascript, but i'm not sure. It definitely has something to do with the "tags" layout of the webpage. I can pull using the code from the first tag titled "Quote" ([http://web.tmxmoney.com/quote.php?qm_symbol=^TTUT](http://web.tmxmoney.com/quote.php?qm_symbol=%5ETTUT)) but not the other tabs.

```
 Option Explicit

  Sub TEST_PULL()

    Dim Look_String As String
    Dim Web_HTML As String
    Dim HTTP_OBJ As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

    Dim xa As Long
    Dim xb As Long

    Select Case HTTP_OBJ.Status
       Case 0: Web_HTML = HTTP_OBJ.responseText
       Case 200: Web_HTML = HTTP_OBJ.responseText **'THE ERROR IS CAUSED HERE**
       Case Else: GoTo ERROR_LABEL:
    End Select

    Look_String = "quote-tabs-content"
    xa = IIf(IsNumeric(Look_String), Look_String, InStr(Web_HTML, Look_String))
    xb = IIf(xa + 32767 <= Len(Web_HTML), 32767, Len(Web_HTML) - xa + 1)
    Web_HTML = Mid(Web_HTML, xa, xb)

  ERROR_LABEL:

  End Sub
```

### Can someone please help me figure out

1. Why this is happening
2. How I can successfully pull that pricing data

It would be a huge help!!! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not you, it's them.

The response headers for the page which is causing the error specify an encoding which doesn't exist: ISO-8559-1. ISO 8559 has nothing to do with text encoding - it actually relates to the sizing of clothes. This should almost certainly be ISO-8859-1 instead.

[image: Chrome developer tools window showing the response headers from a webpage. The encoding of ISO-8559-1 is circled in red]

The quote page which is successfully being read has the correct ISO-8859-1 encoding.

To get around this issue, use the [responseBody property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms756095(v=vs.85).aspx) which contains the raw bytes before decoding. The [StrConv function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264628.aspx) can then attempt to convert those bytes into a Unicode string (although this might not produce correct results in all cases), like this:

`Case 200: Web_HTML = StrConv(HTTP_OBJ.responseBody, vbUnicode)`

Comment: Thanks, I ended up just grabbing the actual text on the website and sparcing through that.